# Compose extension task module does not work on chat not initiated peoples

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a app with compose extension,, compose extension to open a task module it working as expected with the already started conversation users, but throws an error for the people whom i did not have started the conversation..
error - errorMessage: 'Invoke failed due to internal error: Invoke failed: something went wrong in ProcessInvoke'
while opening task module it says something went wrong please try again..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCTU.png)

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will let you know once we have any update.

Comment: We are able to repro your issue at our end. We have raised a bug for it. We will inform you once we have any updates of bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is **by design** behaviour.
Compose extension task module does not work on chat not initiated peoples.

Comment: Please let us know then how it works for the praise inbuild application with chat not initiated peoples. we want to build on the same way by throwing message to initiate chat before using messaging extension task module.

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. we will update you soon

Comment: Any updates on this ...???

Comment: Apps like Praise determine the state of chat and return respective UI.
If the chat is not initiated yet, then client either sends fake conversationId/chatId/channelId (i.e., format "19:preview-<uuid>") or sends empty strings in all these fields. Apps looks for these conditions and if it succeeds, then shows a message to initiate chat before using ME task module.